# simpleCV and Raspberry Pi: no module named simplecv

Tags: python, opencv, module, raspberry-pi, simplecv

**No module named SimpleCv**

I installed simplecv on my RPi using the tutorial link: http://simplecv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/HOWTO-Install%20on%20RaspberryPi.html and installed svgwrite.

I have the simplecv working alone, but when running a python file I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my-file.py", line 1, in <module>
    from SimpleCv import *
ImportError: No module named SimpleCv
```

Is it to do with that my Python and simplecv are in different locations?

`which python` gives: `/usr/bin/python`

`which simplecv` gives: `/usr/local/bin/simplecv`

Many thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 2):

Resolved!

For future readers make sure you capitalise all 3 letters in `from SimpleCV import *`

Stupid mistake, thought I'd tried every combination of capitals.